# nodejs memory leak with no heap issue

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

Ok, this is general question , looking for some hint here and filling the gap in my nodejs understanding.
I cleary have a memory leak but it doesn't appears in the heap. To have a broad idea, the stack is express,postgres,rabbit consumer to socketio, node-cache

[image]

So pm2 is showing the global memory is increasing, clearly there is a memory leak.
I've done snapshots and everything seems ok, we have tested with Jmeter and no issues appeared.
So what kind of category of memory leak it is ? What kind of operation in general can have this kind of effect ?